# Parse messaging app, need to find a way to delay code execution until deleteAllInBackground finishes executing. Detailed code included

Tags: ios, asynchronous, parse-platform

Having some issues with my code, I am building a simple messaging system using the Parse framework. I need to somehow delay the call of a method until a background process is finished executing. Code is below. First I register the UIViewController as an observer for a Parse Push Notification. When a push is received the method **receivedPush** is called. Received push then calls **displayMessages**.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];


     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(receivedMessage) name:@"receivedPush" object:nil];
}


-(void)receivedMessage
{
   [self displayMessages];

}


-(void)displayMessages
{

    //here I want to cycle through the message objects

    NSMutableArray *toDelete = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    PFQuery *messageBankQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"messageBank"];
    [messageBankQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser].username];
    [messageBankQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if(!error) {

            PFObject *messageBank = objects[0];
            PFRelation *receivedMessages = [messageBank relationForKey:@"receivedMessages"];
            PFQuery *receivedMessagesQuery = [receivedMessages query];
            [receivedMessagesQuery orderByAscending:@"createdAt"];

            [receivedMessagesQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

                if((!error) &&([objects count]>0)) {

                    for(PFObject *message in objects) {

                        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Push!" message:miao[@"username"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                        [alert show];

                        //add to the delete items array
                        [toDelete addObject:message];



                    }



                        if([toDelete count]>0) {
                            //delete all using the array, single API call
                            [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:toDelete];

                        }


                }//end if

            }];//end receivedMessagesQuery

        }

    }];//end messageBankQuery



}
```

In **displayMessages** the program first queries the messageBank. The message bank is a class that contains usernames that point to instances of the message class. Each message is put in an array and displayed as a UIAlertView (this is just temporary and for testing purposes).

The code functions as it should but there is a big problem in that if a Push Notification is received and receivedMessages and then displayMessages is called **[PFObject deleteAllInBackground:toDelete];** runs in the background so if messages are received too quickly the program will display duplicate messages as they have not yet finished deleting. What I need to do is wait for **deleteAllInBackground** to finish before allowing displayMessages to be called. I have tried using an NSOperations queue but this doesn't help because if **displayMessages** is in a queue it will count as finished even if the background delete is still running. Is there anyway I can get around this? Just need **displayMessages** to wait until **deleteAllInBackground** to finish before retuning. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Going around in circles here! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `deleteAllInBackground:block:` so that you know when the delete is complete.

Your `NSOperationQueue` suggestion is a good one, but you need to do a little work to create an operation which continues to be 'running' until the end of all of the asynchronous processing is complete. There are a few guides, like [this one](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/).

Comment: I can use deleteAllInBackground:block but how would that help? I could have a flag variable such as BOOL isDeleting and set that to NO when the block finishes execution but the problem is that because I am using Push Notifications receivedMessages can be called at anytime and it is just called once. So perhaps it is called and isDeleting is YES. Where do I go from there? Can only think of using a timer and to keep checking until that variable is set to NO. But it doesn't seem like a nice method.

Comment: You have thought about using an operation queue, and you can, you just need to execute only one operation at a time and to make the operation work asynchronously.

Comment: I tried this  NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(displayMessages) object:nil] and putting this code was in receivedMessages. So it queues it instead of directly calling it. This queues up calls to displayMessages but it isn't waiting for deleteAllInBackground to finish. displayMessaged finishes executing even if deleteAllinBackground is still running.

Comment: Did you read the article I linked to? It is a little out of date but describes the process you need to follow with the operation.

Comment: taking a look at it. If I create a concurrent operation this has _isExecuting  and _isFinished vars. Is this true? And the operation will only finish when _isFinished is set to YES?

Comment: The operation already has them, you just need to set them at the appropriate times

Comment: My bad, in this case your subclass overrides the getters to return your own variables. See Configuring Operations for Concurrent Execution @ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationObjects/OperationObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH101-SW16

Comment: I checked that guide and it worked out for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add a boolean field "Displayed" to the message object stating if the message was shown or not and flag messages that were displayed as true. 
Then in your presentation loop, skip messages that were already shown and in your delete function delete all the messages that are flagged.

Comment: Flagging messages as displayed or not would need API calls though, saveInBackground:block. I would run into the same problem, the presentation loop running whilst saveInBackground is potentially still running in the background modifying the boolean fields.

Comment: if it's too slow to save the changes like my prior method is too slow to delete messages then duplicates will be shown.

Comment: @kek If the problem is presenting duplicates then what you need to do is not display messages that are already in you local toDelete array, and then they are deleted whenever and you don't have to wait for the deletion to end. Make it a property or something so it wont reset between displayMessages calls

Answer (score 0):

You problem is synchronizing display and delete messages. I don't understand the queries you wrote - it is confusing as you deleting messages in displayMessages method!

Keep display message and delete messages separate and create dependency between them like I have suggested in [Concurrent NSOperation and how to set isFinished and isExecuting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154011/concurrent-nsoperation-and-how-to-set-isfinished-and-isexecuting/28154117?noredirect=1#comment44681354_28154117)

You need to re-architect your solution.