# Concurrent NSOperation and how to set isFinished and isExecuting?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to split up my programs flow using NSOperations. I am using the Parse framework to make a simple messaging app. I want to display some messages and then delete them. The display messages shouldn't be called unless the delete operations is finished so I want to try using an NSQueue and add a displayMessages operation to it and then a deleteMessages operation (named MyOperation below). I understand that concurrent operations means they will only execute one after another in a queue fashion. Below is my code for the delete method. Is there a way to manually tell the operation it is finished i.e. setting isFinished or isExecuting??

```
// MyOperation.h
@interface MyOperation : NSOperation {
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *toDelete;
}
@end
And the implementation:

// MyOperation.m
@implementation MyOperation


- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)array
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self == nil)
        return nil;

    _toDelete=array;

}

- (void)main {
    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
    }



//how do I get main to finish execution ONLY after deleteAllInBackground has finished? 


[PFObject deleteAllInBackground:self.toDelete];

    if ([self isCancelled]) {
        NSLog(@"** operation cancelled **");
    }


    NSLog(@"Operation finished");
}


@end
```

right now this code above won't solve my problem. It will queue up the ops but this one will finish even though the deleteAllInBackground is still running. Would really appreciate some help here! thanks

---

other possible solution:

```
-(void)receivedMessage
{
    NSLog(@"push!");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        [self displayMessages];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            if([self.toDelete count]>0) {
                [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:self.toDelete];

            }


        });
    });



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use `dispatch_async` like below;

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        // Display messages
    });
    // Delete messages here
});
```

If you have to use `NSOperationQueue` then I would suggest you to use `KVO` to get notification for task completion; When you setup your queue, do this:

```
[self.deleteQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"delete-operations" options:0 context:NULL];
```

Then do this in your `observeValueForKeyPath`:

```
- (void) observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object 
                     change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == self.deleteQueue && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"delete-operations"]) {
        if ([self.queue.operations count] == 0) {
            // Delete operation done
            // Display messages here
        }
    } else {
        [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object 
                           change:change context:context];
     }
}
```

[EDIT]

```
-(void)receivedMessage {
@synchronized(self) {
    NSLog(@"push!");
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self displayMessages];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void) {
            if([self.toDelete count]>0) {
                // this deletion doesn't matter if background or on main thread as it's already in background queue
                [PFObject deleteAllInBackground:self.toDelete];
            }
        });
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I need to display then delete then display then delete and so on. Using your code above would that mean I need to swap the code around? have the display call at the top and the delete call below it?

Comment: Yes, you will need to swap code(I edited) but idea is to perform delete operation in background queue and display on main queue. Hope that helps.

Comment: edited my question with code using your method. does this look okay? do I need to run deleteAllInBackground or deleteAll (main thread)? Not sure what I need to choose there.

Comment: see edited. you have to call display messages on main thread as it changes UI.

Comment: Use the last edited receivedMessage. It should work for you and it won't block UI!

Comment: what will happen if receivedMessage is called again whilst it is still running? will it wait for it to finish?

Comment: it is reenterant function so shouldn't be problem but if you want to wait then you can synchronise that code block...see edited...

Comment: could you take a look at my original question? details what I want to do. Want to know what approach is best: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28146140/parse-messaging-app-need-to-find-a-way-to-delay-code-execution-until-deletealli

Comment: I tried the dispatch didn't work so well so changed my method to a NSOperation implementation. I think it's working now. You gave me lots of detailed advice. Thank you it was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Use `deleteAll` instead of `deleteAllInBackground` if you want to block the current thread until the deletion is complete.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this as it will make unpleasant UI experience!

Comment: performance wise that's not generally recommend though right? I think I tried that and the console gave me some warnings. Does it stop the UI functioning properly?

Comment: It's not recommended to block the main queue. Don't schedule your `NSOperation` on the main queue if you expect it to be long-running.